# Alternate max_post_size and upload_max_filesize for different subdomains and/or directories php.ini nginx fastcgi php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php

I have nginx and php5-fpm working wonderfully, and `www.mysite.com`, `this.mysite.com`, and `that.mysite.com` all go to different directories elegantly. I have been working on a site for uploading files. I'd like the maximum file size to be 10 GB. For this to work, I have to tell php.ini that max_post_size and upload_max_filesize are 10240 MB instead of the default 2 MB.

I am well aware of the security implications. I would therefore like those php.ini values of 10240 MB to apply ONLY to one or both of:

- `upload.mysite.com`

and/or

- `www.mysite.com/upload`

One option is to also install Apache to listen on a different port, do some redirect/rewrite magic, and have mod_php's php.ini file with the 10240 MB values handle only the uploads site. I'd prefer to not do that.

WITHOUT having a separate web server handle requests to my upload page, how can I accomplish this in a single instance of nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) and set it to the desired value in your `server` blocks. Nginx will directly drop the handling of the request if the request body exceeds the size specified in this directive. Please note that you won't get any `POST` submitted in that case.

Answer (score 0):

With php-fpm you can have several pools running, one for each website.

Then you can alter any php.ini setting inside the pool configuration (but be carefull, you cannot use `MB` or `G` shortcuts), using this syntax inside the pool:

```
; UPLOAD
php_admin_flag[file_uploads]         =1
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir]="/some/path/var/tmp"
;Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. 10240MB *1024 *1024 -> 10737418240
php_value[upload_max_filesize] ="10737418240"
php_admin_value[max_input_time]      = (...)
php_admin_value[post_max_size]  (...)
```

This is really near the available syntax for Apache virtualhosts. PHP configuration has never been stuck in `php.ini` files.

As you can see you can use **php_value** or **php_admin_value**, the big difference is that when using **php_value** the setting can later be altered by the application, using **ini_set** command. So you could use a low value for `upload_max_filesize` and alter it in the application only on the upload script.